# How to layout follow content using CSS?

Tags: html, css, layout

Here is the layout I would like to make:

[image: Layout example]

'input' is 70% width of the screen. 
and the 'second input' is 70% width of 'input'.
'button' is 30% width of 'input'.
'input' is in the middle of the screen.

How can I do so? Thank you.

Comment: You can't. You make a DIV containing both input fields + the button, and make the DIV 70% of the screen. the input will then be 100% of the DIV, second input will be 70% of the DIV and the button will be the last 30% of the DIV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not think this require any special skills. This is a very basic fluid layout. An example

Markup

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <input type="text" id="firstrow_textbox" />
  <input type="text" id="secondrow_textbox" />
  <input type="button" id="secondrow_button" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
#wrapper {
    width: 70%;
}
  #firstrow_textbox { width: 100%; }
  #secondrow_textbox { width: 70%; }
  #secondrow_button { width: 28%; } /* Due to border and all */
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lg9V4/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You can get this to work by creating a wrapper element that has the desired "70% width of the screen," and then size the inputs relative to that.

Example: http://jsbin.com/akeze4

You'll still want to adjust margins and paddings for your specific purpose, but this should be a decent start.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/Husar/gkFhb/2/

Just fine tune margins and padding

Answer (score 0):

layout:

```
<div class="container">
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="input1" /></div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="input2" />
        <input type="button" id="input3" /></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.container { 
    margin: auto;  /* to center the container horizontally */
    width: 70% /* to take the 70% of the parent element */
  }
  #input1 {
    width: 100%; /* to take the 100% of the parent which is the container div  */
  }
  #input2 {
    float: left; /* to align the control on the left */
    width:70%; /* to take the 70% of the parent which is the container div  */
  }
    #input3 {
    float: right; /* to align the control to the right */
    width:29%; /* to take the 29% of the parent which is the container div  */
  }
```

preview: http://jsbin.com/ibeyo5